# Excel formula for creating new rows based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a worksheet where a want to create a new row where there is a value filled in in column AA trough AE and ignoring the blank cells.

I have tried a formula as:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A3,A3)=COUNTA(OFFSET($AA$3:$AF$100,MATCH(A3,$AA$3:$AF$100,0),0)),INDEX($AA$2:$AF$100,MATCH(A3,$AA$2:$AF$100,0)+1),A3)
```

[image: ![Result now]

Waht i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: This is literally two click in PowerQuery if you wouldn't mind using that. Import all 4 columns, highlight the 1st, unpivot the other three and delete the middle column from the result before you load back to Excel.

Comment: Hello JvdV, I cant use the powerQuery i need to wrap it into a formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ms365:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(B2:D7="","",A2:A7&"</s><s>"&B2:D7))&"</s></t>","//s"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:D7),2))
```

Or

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(IF(B2:D7="","</s><s>",A2:A7&"</s><s>"&B2:D7)),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[node()]"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:D7),2))
```

---

For a Dutch version:

```
=INDEX(XML.FILTEREN("<t><s>"&TEKST.COMBINEREN("</s><s>";;ALS(B2:D7="";"";A2:A7&"</s><s>"&B2:D7))&"</s></t>";"//s");REEKS(AANTALARG(B2:D7);2))
```

Or:

```
=INDEX(XML.FILTEREN("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUEREN(ARRAYTOTEXT(ALS(B2:D7="";"</s><s>";A2:A7&"</s><s>"&B2:D7));"; ";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[node()]");REEKS(AANTALARG(B2:D7);2))
```